# is n a constant bounding in a summation

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

I have to calculate a right riemann sum in terms of n. The formula for a right riemann sum is
$\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k\Delta x)*\Delta x $
so in terms of n on a bounded interval of [0,3] is $\frac{3}{n}$
so i rewrote the formula as $\Delta x *\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k\Delta x)$
because n as an upper limit has to be a constant, Even as the limit of n approaches infinity n itself will be just be a very large integer. is this justification accurate?

Comment: "Even as the limit ..." - there is no limit involved here (in fact, you do not wirte $\lim$ anywhere). So what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: I should've clarified, my mistake. The next part of the problem is to take the limit as n approaches infinity to evaluate the actual area, rather than the approximation. But I want to use the same justification. n always has to be a constant bounding right? even in the limit as n approaches infinity, n itself would be a constant? could you bind a summation where n= 2x? that wouldn't work right?